# Numpy installation with intel C++ compiler on Win7

Tags: python, numpy

I am installing numpy 1.11.0 with intel C++/Fortran compiler (Parallel Studio XE 2016, using VS 2013 integration) on Win7 64 bit, Python 3.4. All the configure is according to this tutorial here (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/600681). It is supposed to use the Intel C++ compiler not MSVC 2010. However, installation still returns error.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

With this error, it still returned this one which is not supposed to happen. It seems that it cannot find the Intel C++ compiler.

```
Could not locate executable icc
Could not locate executable ecc
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy build uses the distutils msvc compiler to set variables (MSVCCompiler.init and MSVCCompiler.initialize in intelccompiler.py). Did you try using this with icl (instead of icc), by passing --compiler=intelw to the build step?

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade your pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
And then 
try to install numpy again
pip install numpy.

Otherwise you can use Anaconda or miniconda from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

These distribution contains numpy.